# Command is not working

Tags: java, bukkit

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin
{

    // Logger variable
    Logger myPluginLogger = Bukkit.getLogger();

    // Does when plugin is disabled - console logging
    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        myPluginLogger.info("Disabling Political Parties...");
    }

    // Plugin chat help function
    public void sendPlayerHelp(String permissions, Player player)
    {
        // If player does not belong to a party, show them these commands
        if (permissions == "nonpartisan")
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Political Parties by TerraCraft - version 1.0");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party create <party name> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Start a political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party list " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows a list of all of the current political parties");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party info <party> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows info about a specific party");
        }
        // If a player does belong to a party, show them these commands
        else if (permissions == "inparty")
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Political Parties by TerraCraft - version 1.0");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party leave " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Leave your current political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party list " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows a list of all of the current political parties");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party info <party> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows info about a specific party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party deposit <amount> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Deposit a specific sum into the party bank account");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party chat <message> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Say specified message in party chat");
        }
        // If a player is the leader of a party, show them these commands
        else if (permissions == "partyleader")
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Political Parties by TerraCraft - version 1.0");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party delete " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Deletes your current political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party list " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows a list of all of the current political parties");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party info <party> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Shows info about a specific party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party deposit <amount> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Deposit a specific sum into the party bank account");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party withdraw <amount> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Withdraw a specific sum from the party bank account");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party policy <add|remove> [index] [message] " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Add or remove a specific policy to/from your political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party invite <player> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Invite a player to your political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party kick <player> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Kick a player from your political party");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party giveleader <player> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Resign yourself as party leader and give it to another player");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/party chat <message> " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Say specified message in party chat");    
        }
    }

    // Command function
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender theSender, Command cmd, String[] args, String commandLabel)
    {
        // Party command
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("party"))
        {
            Player player = (Player) theSender;

            // If no arguments are specified, or if the first argument is equal to help, or ?, show them help
            if (args.length == 0 || args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help") || args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("?"))
            {
                sendPlayerHelp("nonpartisan", player);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hello, I have previously created basic Bukkit server plugins, and have worked properly. I am creating a new one, but for some reason, it will not run the command. Just to clarify, the plugin YAML is correctly done (and so are the imports, I just did not feel the need to include them), and there are no compiling errors. I have the command in the command YAML file, and when I load the plugin, it shows up in my plugins list, and when I do /help. When I run the command it just returns the usage: '/party', but will not do the other stuff (send the player the help message). I am not quite sure why it is not working. Have I forgot something by mistake? Also, this is my first question, so apologies if it is not up to standards.

Comment: Why is it asking for player name?

Comment: I suggest removing your empty `else` blocks and changing how you compare `Strings` from `==` to `.equals()` This doesn't fix the problem, just some tips

Comment: The only way the first command will execute is if player name is party

Comment: I don't approve of how your commands are setup. I still don't get why first command is asking for name. But you should do your commands # of args ex. /PoParty help *runs help. Because if you do /help it will interfere with bukkit /help

Comment: None have answered my question... and it is set up so when you do /party help it shows help. And it is asking for player name because it needs the sender in the help text method... why is my post being downvoted?

Comment: @Dr_Derek It's poorly setup post plus User find it useless which I find is Useful for others I will show you how to setup your commands give me a minute to post.

Comment: @Dr_Derek Be sure to tag me next time or else I wont get notified

Comment: @Dr_Derek Did I answer your question below?

Comment: @Tarson No, but it is resolved now. I appreciate you trying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the person above me is saying, but let me explain:
Yes, using cmd.getName() is better than commandLabel and here's why:
When you register a command in your plugin.yml, you have to give it a name. Then under that name you can set things like it's description, permissions, etc. and most importantly in this case - its aliases. When you set its aliases, the command will be run when any of those aliases are called in a command. The label will be the exact alias that was run, and the cmd.getName() will be the name of the command you registered.
As for your problem, I'm guessing it's on this line here:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender theSender, Command cmd, String[] args, String commandLabel)
```

It should be

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender theSender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
```

The order is always CommandSender, Command, String, String[].
You should add the @Override tag above your onCommand method so errors like that will be thrown and you will know that's the problem.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the beginning you have `if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("party"))` which if I'm not mistaking is asking command prompt/cmd to grab the user name.

What I believe you want is to array your commands. So for ex. `/party help, /party setup ...`

In the code I have put in some comments to help you apply to your plugin.

To begin you want to setup your first command by doing something like this:

```
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("PoP") || label.equalsIgnoreCase("PoliticalParty")){
//this will be your first command so you want to replace cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("party") as that is really wrong


//below tells the user if command is just "POP" then give user message
    if(args.length == 0){//if less then 0 input
                        player.sendMessage("Wrong command type /pop help");
                    }
```

Now before closing the command yet you now want to add the Argument that if `args.length`is more then one. 
So underneath the code above put this in:

```
                else if(args.length >= 1){
            //this will ask args if it has a valid amount of args and will now check for word help
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")){
        player.sendMessage("This is my plugin my only command so far is /pop")
        }

        //ok now if(args.length >= 1) has a invalid argument we should let the user now. so at the very end add else stament
    else {
                    player.sendMessage("invalid argument");
}
}
//close from first argument}
```

Comment: Ask any questions you may have!

Comment: BTW may I suggest changing your plugin command /party may run into another users plugin or essentials wich most servers have. try ex. /pop

Comment: Yes, thank you. The Bukkit developers actually advise against using commandLabel rather than cmd.getName() but I will give it a whirl.

Comment: Dr_Derek Nah. You have to use commandLabel for commands. Tell me if you fully resolve and get it working. Command setup is a hard tricky step making sure each command a user puts in is always followed by a output. To always let the user know.